# Is watching YouTube movies haram?? I mean uploaded by some third party users

Tags: halal-haram, internet, movies

My question is whether watching YouTube movies is haram?? But when it comes to watching movies....my thought is YouTube users usually upload movies..  but they may or may not have their rights towards that movie... I studied that torrent downloading is equal to theft... So I avoided that... But YouTube has plenty of movies... But they may or may not belong to the production house... These movies may be uploaded by third parties.... So it will also become theft ???? And my another question is watching movies itself is haram .... Then why comes these type of haram or halal in movies.... Since it's haram, why we cannot watch by any source we get.... why we should see haram inside of another haram???? Its like seeing haram inside of another haram ..... kindly answer this question ... Thank you before itswlf

Comment: watching movie is haram.. it does not matter, if you watch form tv,youtube or others sources ...........

Comment: Salam and welcoem to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam To learn more about out site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please be aware that these are multiple questions in one post some (if not all) have been prior addressed and answered on the site. Please check the site first for answers and ask a good (new) question see also [ask].